# JQuery validation: required( dependency-expression )

Tags: jquery-plugins

I want a field to become required only when a specific option is selected or a specific radio button is selected or when a specific string is entered in a text input field (All of the required( dependency-expression ) examples I can find assume that the dependency is whether an input is checked / unchecked or filled/unfilled in the case of text fields)

Here is an example of what I need, based on a radio section:

Marital Status (the required field):

```
<input name="status" id='status'type="radio" value="couple" checked="checked" />
<input name="status" id='status'type="radio" value="single male"  />
<input name="status" id='status'type="radio" value="single female" />
```

Partners Name (the dependent field - required only when 'Couple' is selected from above)

```
<input name="partner" type="text"  id="partner">
```

Example 2: Required field = Venue

```
<select name="venue" id="venue">
<option value="">Please select venue</option>
<option>London EC1</option>
<option>London E9</option>
<option>Birmingham</option>
```

etc.
Dependent field = user (only required for one of the above selections, say 'Birmingham')

```
<input name="user" type="text" id="user">
```

How do I adapt the example shown athttp://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression for the above situations?

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    details: {
      required: "#other:checked"
    }
  }, debug:true
});
$("#other").click(function() {
  $("#details").valid();
});
```

I have tried:

```
user: {
      required: "#venue:('birmingham')"
    }
```

and

```
partner: {
      required: "#status:('couple')"
    }
```

but these have the effect of making user and partner required regardless of results in venue and status

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first one, your radio inputs should have different id's:

```
<input name="status" id='statusCouple' type="radio" value="couple" checked="checked" />
<input name="status" id='statusSingleMale' type="radio" value="single male"  />
<input name="status" id='statusSignleFemale' type="radio" value="single female" />
```

Then your rule can look like this:

```
partner: {
  required: "#statusCouple:checked"
}
```

For the second one, just make your rule like this:

```
user: {
  required: function(element) { return $("#venue").val() == 'Birmingham'; }
}
```

Should do the trick.